# Drawing multiple rectangles in an xml drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I'm trying to figure out how to create a 3x3 row of small rectangles in an android xml drawable.
This isn't really getting me close (2 small rects, but they overlap):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="20dp" android:top="20dp" android:right="25dp" android:bottom="25dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#fff" />
            <solid android:color="#00FF0000" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:left="30dp" android:top="30dp" android:right="35dp" android:bottom="25dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#fff" />
            <solid android:color="#00FF0000" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <size android:width="10dp"
                  android:height="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 7):

Part of the problem is that the individual items in a layer-list are scaled to the overall size of the drawable. As described in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), you can get around this by wrapping the small squares in a `bitmap` drawable. Something like this might work. First, define the basic shape as a separate drawable:

**drawable/square.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#fff" />
    <solid android:color="#00FF0000" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

(EDIT: It would be nice if you could do the above, but, unfortunately, as @Someone Somewhere pointed out in a comment, you can't reference shape drawables from within a `<bitmap>` tag. You'll have to create the square as an actual bitmap graphic for the rest of this to work.)

Then you can define a layer-list that won't scale the individual squares:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- first row -->
    <item android:left="20dp" android:top="20dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
    <item android:left="35dp" android:top="20dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
    <item android:left="50dp" android:top="20dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>

    <!-- second row -->
    <item android:left="20dp" android:top="35dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
    <item android:left="35dp" android:top="35dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
    <item android:left="50dp" android:top="35dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>

    <!-- third row -->
    <item android:left="20dp" android:top="50dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
    <item android:left="35dp" android:top="50dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
    <item android:left="50dp" android:top="50dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/square" android:gravity="top|left" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I haven't tested this, so it may be a bit off, but you should be able to tweak it to get what you want. The important thing is to get rid of the scaling.

Comment: I like where this is going, but nothing is showing up on my display.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1059096 - Hm. I don't know why it isn't working. (Actually, there's one big problem: every time the `<bitmap>` tag appears, it's wrong. It should be: `<scale android:drawable="@drawable/square" android:scaleGravity="top|left" />`. The `<bitmap>` drawable requires a reference to a raw bitmap and I was trying to use it to reference `<shape>` drawable.) But even with that change, it doesn't work (as I just confirmed). I'll look into it more when I have a bit more time. It's very odd.

Comment: **this doesn't work** a bitmap can not load an xml shape - it results in an error message `<bitmap> requires a valid src attribute`. So it would seem that something as basic as generating an image from layers of shapes isn't even possible.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere - I'm not sure what you're trying, but it isn't what I posted. The code I posted has valid `src` attributes for all the `<bitmap>` tags.

Comment: I learned yesterday that `<bitmap>` is unable to load a `<shape>`. For it to work, you have to have a true image.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere - How about that. I guess OP will have to use an actual graphics file for the square.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [documentation of Layer Lists](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).

It will clear up, that `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` are attributes in **dimension** for the offsets of the item: how far the item itself should be placed from the border of it's parent (the layer-list).

If you know that your layer-list is say 130 dp wide and 130 dp high, and you want 3x3 rectangles there, the first's offsets should be

```
top: 10
left: 10
bottom: 90
right: 90
```

and the next's (first row, second column):

```
top: 10
left: 50
bottom: 90
right: 50
```

Comment: and the second row

top: 50
left: 10
bottom: 50
right: 90

Third row 

top: 90
left: 10
bottom: 10
right: 90

Answer (score 0):

As the discussion has already revealed, using bitmap is restricted to real bitmaps; other (XML) drawables cannot be used here.

ScaleDrawables should be a suitable solution for you. They should offer the attributes you need to adjust their position within the resulting bounding box.

However, ScaleDrawables suffer from the fact that they are intended for animations. They appear to start with a level of 0, which makes them invisibly small. Also, it does not seem possible to set the level in XML.

If you can live with setting a level on your ScaleDrawables in your code, give it a try.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351271/android-layer-list-does-not-show-scale-drawable-item/).